# Does a certain type count as "Type-Blooded" for feat prereqs?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats

There are several feats such as Aberration Blooded, Fiend Blooded etc. that open up the way to tons of other aberration and fiend related feats respectively. Fluff-wise, the logic behind these feats is that you have a distant ancestor that is one of the aforementioned types, and the inherent energy in the blood of that type flows through you.

Now... What if you actually HAVE the aberration or fiend type? You too have this blood in your veins- More so than anyone else. Would this qualify you for the feats in the  blooded tree of your type? Or do you NEED the  blooded feat?

Answer (score 6):

Rules-as-written, if a feat has another feat listed as a prerequisite, then you must have that feat in order to take the first feat, unless you specifically have some other ability that lets you forgo the prerequisite. This is the case no matter what the narrative justification of those feats are; being an Aberration does not inherently qualify you for Aberrant feats. In fact, by the RAW, aberrations can never take those aberrant feats, because in order to qualify for the *[Aberration Blood](http://therafimrpg.wikidot.com/aberration-blood)* prerequisite feat, you must be of type Humanoid.

You could consider this reasonable, since if you already are an Aberration, presumably you are a specific race of Aberration which already has its own traits and qualities. The feats are there to represent the nebulous influence of some unknown Aberrant history in your bloodline, so what exactly that influence was isn't nailed down and you could conceivably have many different inherited traits. A mind flayer, on the other hand, is just a mind flayer, unless you put a template on it.

Of course, aberrations are aberrations and mutation is hardly an uncommon theme. If I were your GM, I would personally be inclined to allow characters with such matching types to take feats from the family without needing to take an "X Blood[ed]" prerequisite - it's hardly the most egregious powergaming in a game which already allows such diverse characters, and I am given to understand that the feats in such families are pretty sub-optimal choices anyway.

Comment: It’s probably worth noting that literally *every single one* of those feat series are nearly worthless anyway. Seriously, they kept repeating that concept and have basically never printed a decent feat while doing so.

Comment: @KRyan so noted.